# JSF - Como passar uma função do Bean como argumento de uma função em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema em JSF, e tenho a seguinte necessidade: Eu gostaria de passar uma função do bean como argumento de uma função minha em JS, para que eu determinado momento futuro eu possa chamar tal função.
Por exemplo:

```
..Server Side..
class oi{
void diga ola(){}
}
....Xhtml Page....
function foo(f){}
foo(#{oi.ola()});
.....
```

Ah, vc poderia dizer para eu usar o "p:remoteCommand" que é um componente do primefaces,entretanto o código iria ficar ridiculamente grande. Eu já observei que ele gera uma função chamada de "PrimeFaces.ab(...)", mas infelizmente não entendi como ele reconhece a função que deve ser chamada e não encontrei uma documentação que mostra o seu funcionamento.

O que eu quero fazer é um dialog onde o conteúdo seja genérico, e essa funcionalidade já funciona. Entretanto, eu gostaria ter a possibilidade de chamar uma função do bean quando o dialog for fechado
assim que está hj:

```
<p:menuitem action="#{função quando abre dialog}" oncomplete="wizardComponent.openDialog('título do dialog,'conteudododialog.xhtml')" value="texto apresentado no menu "/>
```

No caso eu queria passar mais um argumento para função, assim:

```
openDialog("título do dialog,'conteudododialog.xhtml', #{função a ser chamada quando o dialog fechar})
```

Qualquer sugestão é bem vinda.

Answer (score 0):

Thaylon, especifique um *listener* através de um evento *ajax:*

```
<p:dialog id="suaDialog" widgetVar="suaDialog" header="Sua Dialog"       
          resizable="false" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
    <p:ajax event="close" update="growl" listener="#{dialogBean.suaFuncaoDeFechamento}" />

    <!-- Conteúdo da dialog -->
</p:dialog>
```

Vale a pena dar uma olhada no [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/events.xhtml).

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela sugestão. Conseguir o evento de fechar não é o meu  problema. O que eu quero é passar é o #{dialogBean.suaFuncaoDeFechamento} como argumento de uma função javascript minha, pois eu gerencio o dialog por JS, e no caso eu quero que a solução seja genérica.

Comment: Já olhou o funcionamento do `PrimeFaces.ab`, que é um atalho para `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxRequest`? Exemplo: `PrimeFaces.ab({formId:'dialogForm',source:'dialogForm:componenteQualquerId',process:'@all',update:'growl'})` Com ele, você pode chamar seus métodos no *bean* via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como faz a passagem de função por parâmetros, mas eu precisei fazer algo para gerenciar dialogs de maneira padronizada semelhante ao que vc está querendo e funcionou por outro caminho, veja se serve ao seu projeto:

No XHTML principal: faço um include da dialog, passo como parâmetro uma variável `output` e `componentesParaAtualizar` (que é aceito pela EL - não consegui passar uma função via param) e chamo normalmente o dialog - `PF('widgetVarDialog').show()`.

```
<ui:include src="../dialog/dialog.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="output" value="#{bean.dialogFechada}" />
    <ui:param name="componentesParaAtualizar" value="idComponente1" />
</ui:include>
```

No dialog.xhtml: O dialog tem um link para fechar que chama uma função do bean `fecharDialog()`. Se fosse algo estático, bastaria modificar essa função que tudo estaria resolvido, mas como o que vou fazer é variável, uso o `setPropertyActionListener` para simular um evento:

```
<p:commandLink title="Fechar" action="#{bean.fecharDialog()}" ajax="true" update="#{componentesParaAtualizar}" process="@this">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{output}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

No bean: A variável `output` que passei como parâmetro possui um método extra no `setDialogFechada()` que faz o que preciso. Dessa maneira, a dialog é genérica e quando é fechada, executa o método que preciso.

```
private boolean dialogFechada;

public boolean isDialogFechada() {
    return this.dialogFechada;
}

public void setDialogFechada(boolean dialogFechada) {
    this.dialogFechada = dialogFechada;
    this.metodoAExecutarQuandoFecharADialog();
}

private void metodoAExecutarQuandoFecharADialog() {
    // Método a executar
}

public void fecharDialog() {
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('widgetVarDialog').hide();");
}
```